# What is the correct Object Pronoun to complete the sentence "I don't play soccer and volleyball because I don't like ____"

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, personal-pronouns

What's the correct object pronoun to complete the following sentence, "it" or "them"?

"I don't play soccer and volleyball because I don't like _____."

**Edit:** Do I use the plural "them" because the sentence is referring to "soccer and volleyball" (two sports), or do I use the singular "it" because the sentence is referring to "I don't like to play".

I thought at first that the correct sentence is "I don't like to play soccer and volleyball because I don't like it". Am I correct?

Comment: No; though English does allow for (and I myself would go so far as to recommend) 'notional agreement', as in 'Health and safety is our main priority at the moment', no practised native speaker would advise a singular verb form in this case. If you want to emphasise a single overarching reason, you'd need say 'I don't play soccer and / or  volleyball because I don't like strenuous exercise / sport / ball games / .... //// Do many consider soccer and volleyball 'a single action'? I think you mean 'are fairly closely related, members of the set of team ball-games / sports'.

Comment: Or *I don't play soccer and volleyball because I don't like to*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**The pronoun agrees with the original noun.**

The noun phrase is plural ("soccer and volleyball" are two things) so the pronoun is plural also.

> I don't play soccer and volleyball because I don't like them.

Some would argue that "I don't play soccer *or* volleyball..." would be better.

The only very rare exception to this is when the "X and Y" phrase refers to a singular item. For example

> I don't play rhythm and blues because I don't like it.

"Rhythm and blues" is the name of a singular style of music, and so the pronoun would therefore be singular.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got it.

Comment: @AdrianoHenriqueNogara If this answered your question, please upvote (use the uparrow on the left of the answer) and accept (click the tick box to the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I would put: "I don't play soccer and volleyball because I don't like ***either of them***."

Hope this helps.

Comment: helped a lot. Thank you very much.